# How to simplify the Boolean expression (A'B+C)'(C+A)?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am trying to solve the following problem:

(A'B+C)'(C+A)

= (AB'+C')(C+A)

= AB'C+AB'A+C'C+C'A

= AB'C+AB'A+0+C'A

= AB'C+AB'+C'A

Than what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have applied De Morgan incorrectly in the first step...
$$(A'B+C)'(C+A)=((A'B)'C')(C+A)$$
$$=(A+B')C'(C+A)=(A+B')C'A=AC'$$

Answer (score 0):

$(A'B+C)' = (A'B)'C' = (A+B')C'$ to begin with.

Comment: Did I make a mistake here: (A'B+C)'(C+A) = (AB'+C')(C+A)? Rather shouldn't it be (A'B+C)'(C+A) = (AB'C')(C+A)?

Comment: Seems like a different formula